# How to replace characters at certain positions in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a fictional account number that I'm trying to import and the year is always stored in the 10th and 11th position.  All the other characters around it could be random.  Whilst its easy in say C#, how do I replace the 10th and 11th character with the new year in T-SQL?

```
XX-19XXXX19-A
YY-19YYYY19/B
```

so the replacement is

```
XX-19XXXX20-A
XX-19XXXX20/B
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [STUFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to get the expected results:

Statement:

```
SELECT STUFF(AccNo, 10, 2, '20') AS AccNo
FROM (VALUES ('XX-19XXXX19-A'), ('YY-19YYYY19/B')) v (AccNo)
```

Result:

```
AccNo
XX-19XXXX20-A
YY-19YYYY20/B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stuff()` :

```
SELECT STUFF(AccNo, 10, 2, RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select STUFF(YourID, starting_index, 2, thenewvalue) from yourtable
```